# How to extract text and preserve shading effects?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a logo and I am trying to extract the text while preserving the shading effects.[image: Here is the image]

I have tried several approaches, such as using magic wand to delete the background color, but this results in artifacts as you can imagine near the text and icon boundaries. Does anyone know of another approach that will allow me to extract the text and icon with the shading so I can save as transparent png?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Create a path around the text and instrument/moon thing, make it into a vector mask, then re-apply a new shadow on it.

Comment: Thanks - very simple approach. I would vote up but don't have reputation points!

Comment: @BrianHuether you can mark this the correct answer if you feel it does so, welcome to wait and see if anyone else has ideas too. Helps the site stay organized (otherwise bot eventually bumps things) and you'll get some rep for it.